# Angular2 how to call rest void post api

Tags: angular, rest

I have a rest api to send email to user, it is a void post method. How do I call this method using angular2? I tested this api and was able to receive emails. However when I call this method from my angular http post, it is not working. Here is my code:

```
    sendEMailToUser(email: string, subject: string, emailbody: string): 
    Observable<void> {
       const link = constants.URL2 + 'SendEMailToUser';
       const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
       const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });        
       const body = {
          'email_address': email,
          'subject': subject,
          'body': emailbody
       }

      return this.http.post(link, body, options)
      .map((response: Response) => {})
      .catch(this.handleError)
 }
```

Comment: Did you subscribe to the method? Also, you don't have to map Response since it is void.

Comment: Ops, I forgot to subscribe, now it is working, thank you!